# How to detect wrong Relaxed order in Rust

Tags: rust

from my understanding, the following test can be flaky on weak ordering machine:

```
    #[tokio::test(flavor = "multi_thread")]
    async fn test_ready() {
        let ready = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));
        let concurret_vec = Arc::new(concurrent_queue::ConcurrentQueue::<usize>::bounded(1));

        let concurret_vec_copy = concurret_vec.clone();
        let ready_copy = ready.clone();
        let handle1 = tokio::spawn(async move {
            concurret_vec_copy.push(1).unwrap();
            ready_copy.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
        });

        let concurret_vec_copy = concurret_vec.clone();
        let ready_copy = ready.clone();
        let handle2 = tokio::spawn(async move {
            while !ready_copy.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10)).await;
            }

            assert_eq!(concurret_vec_copy.pop().unwrap(), 1);
        });

        handle1.await.unwrap();
        handle2.await.unwrap();
    }
```

Because Relaxed order is used, there is no happens-before relationship established, so we may see `concurret_vec_copy` empty in the second thread even if `ready_copy` returns true. We need `Acquire`/`Release` here to establish happens before relationship.

But such test is not flaky on my Mac M2 machine, how can we detect wrong usage of Relaxed with tests?

Comment: Take a look at the [loom](https://crates.io/crates/loom) crate. I can be used to simulate all possible concurrent permutations and attest that there are no edge cases.